# Lua - Uploading to Pastebin

Tags: api, upload, lua, roblox, pastebin

Note that this is Roblox's version of lua.
I want to upload a table to Pastebin. Here is what I have for Pastebin.

```
h = game:GetService'HttpService'
JSON = h:JSONEncode(ImgScript) --ImgScript is a table formatted like {{x,y,z}, {x,y,z}, {x,y,z}, etc.}
h:PostAsync('http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php','&api_dev_key=CensoredDevKey&api_option=paste&api_paste_code=' .. JSON)
```

This doesn't work, and I can't seem to figure out why.

EDIT:
I also tried this and it didn't work.

```
h = game:GetService'HttpService'
api_params = {
    ["api_dev_key"] = "CensoredDevKey",
    ["api_option"] = "paste",
    ["api_paste_code"] = ImgScript
}
api_params = h:JSONEncode(api_params)
h:PostAsync('http://www.pastebin.com/api/api_post.php', api_params)
```

EDIT:
I also tried this and it didn't work:

```
h = game:GetService'HttpService'
JSON = h:JSONEncode(ImgScript) --ImgScript is a table formatted like {{x,y,z}, {x,y,z}, {x,y,z}, etc.}
data = h:UrlEncode('&api_dev_key=CensoredDevKey&api_option=paste&api_paste_code=' .. JSON)
h:PostAsync('http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php', data)
```

Comment: I don't think the pastebin API uses JSON encoding?  Your first approach is close... perhaps simply urlencode the paste code instead of JSON encoding it?

Comment: I tried using UrlEncode instead of JSONEncode on just the paste data, and on all 3 required parameters, but none worked.

Comment: Check out me 'DigitalVeer'. I have an open sourced example on my profile for posting to pastebin. It's under Skype cleaner. I'll upload a solution tomorrow when on a computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've finished the code, but sadly, Roblox limits the `PostAsync` size to 256 bytes so any upload larger than that will be GZIPed (up to 1024kb), which Pastebin doesn't know what to do with.

Anyhow, I've released the code here:
http://www.roblox.com/Pastebin-Upload-item?id=302297532

It is:

```
--Created by GShocked. PM me if you have questions!

h = game:GetService'HttpService'
api_dev_key = '' --Your Pastebin developer key goes here. Log in first, and then you can find it at pastebin.com/api
api_paste_code = '' --The content of your new paste
api_paste_private = '1' --0 public; 1 unlisted; 2 private
api_paste_name = '' --Name your new paste
api_paste_expire_date = 'N' --N for never expire, 10M for 10 minutes, etc.
api_paste_format = 'lua' --The syntax highlighting
api_user_key = '' --This is generated using the login info
api_paste_name = h:UrlEncode(api_paste_name)
api_paste_code = h:UrlEncode(api_paste_code)
username = '' --Your Pastebin username goes here
password = '' --Your Pastebin password goes here

api_user_key = h:PostAsync(
    'http://pastebin.com/api/api_login.php',
    'api_dev_key=' .. api_dev_key .. '&api_user_name=' .. username .. '&api_user_password=' .. password,
    2
)
print(api_user_key) --DON'T DELETE THIS! IT IS ESSENTIAL FOR THE USER KEY TO BE GENERATED!
h:PostAsync(
    'http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php',
    'api_option=paste&api_user_key=' .. api_user_key .. '&api_paste_private=' .. api_paste_private .. '&api_paste_name=' .. api_paste_name .. '&api_paste_expire_date=' .. api_paste_expire_date .. '&api_paste_format=' .. api_paste_format .. '&api_dev_key=' .. api_dev_key .. '&api_paste_code=' .. api_paste_code,
    2
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
h = game:GetService'HttpService'
pasteData = h:UrlEncode( h:JSONEncode(ImgScript) )
h:PostAsync(
    'http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php',
    'api_dev_key=CensoredDevKey&api_option=paste&api_paste_code=' .. pasteData,
    2
)
```

The last parameter, `2` [specifies that](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Enum/HttpContentType) the data being sent is `Application/Url-Encoded`.

I think that this should do the trick. Do inform here if it doesn't.

PS: Where are you receiving the result from this POST request?

Comment: I realized that I also need a login and password to be sent to pastebin, not just the dev key. So that'd need to be included, but I'd also need to wait for a response from pastebin giving the information required (the api_user_key) to upload a paste. I'm not sure how I would wait for that response though.